# If inside of foreach always returns false

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I'm working on a set of routines that will check a visitors ip address against a list of know back actors. The IF statement always returns a fale, even if I set the ip to a know bad ip. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$toratora="NO DNSBL";

$filename = 'converted.txt';
$contents = file($filename);

foreach($contents as $line):
$newline = ("$line "); //Add a space after each ip.
//If (int) is in front of $newline & $ip, then always true.
//If (int) is not in front of $newline & $ip, then always false.
if ($line == $ip): 
$toratora="YES DNSBL";
endif; 
endforeach;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `$newline` when you check `$line`?  Also what is `$ip` (there is no way to answer without that value)  Plus I hate the alternative syntax style, the non `{}` when it's in code, it's much better in HTML... But that is an opinion.  Also the `("$line ")` doesn't need the `()`

Comment: AKA, if's don't lie.  So baring any syntax errors, that i don't see, your two values are not equal.  That is the simple answer....

Comment: Try using `trim()` in both `$line` and `$ip` in `$line == $ip` as `trim($line) == ($ip)` as there maybe whitespace(s) in either that's why it returns false.

Comment: you need to provide more information in order to get anything useful. Try debugging the code, at least using var_dump on some values and checking why the comparison always returns false. It might be spaces, carriage returns...

Comment: Hi all. Thank you for all the responses.  The ip comes from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ... The rsync file that I get is in bind format, so it's all one continuous line. That's why I added the $newline, so there would be a space after each ip in the file. Sorry for the confusion. It's supposed to be $newline==$ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your $line values, if you look at the manual for [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) you'll see that

> Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, **with the
>   newline still attached**

Since your $ip variable (i'm guessing) does not have a newline on the end, comparison will fail. As has been suggested in the comments, you should trim both $line and $ip i.e.

```
if (trim($line) == trim($ip)): 
$toratora="YES DNSBL";
endif;
```

Comment: Thank you!  That worked.  Is it a common problem with if statements to need the 'trim'?

Comment: No, you just need the trim in this case because either or both values could have whitespace on either end and == is an exact match, so with differing whitespace on the two values it won't match. If this solves your problem please mark it accepted. thanks...

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you again.